# R Tidyverse calculating mean() of filtered subset

Tags: r, mean

in the R tidyverse chapter 5.6.4 it is said:

```
# What proportion of flights are delayed by more than an hour?
not_cancelled %>% 
  group_by(year, month, day) %>% 
  summarise(hour_perc = mean(arr_delay > 60))
```

but is this really the percentage of those flights that are delayed by more than an hour, compared to the total number of delays of all flights?

Because I am subsetting the data in the `mean()` function by filtering out those data points that have `arr_delay <= 60`, so I am excluding a part of all the data points, and then taking only the mean of the filtered data, which is the mean of only those data points that have `arr_delay > 60`, or not?  I ask because I am not totally sure how this `mean()` function works. Otherwise, I would have to count the subset of all flights that have `arr_delay >60` and then divide by total number of flights ?

To recap, essentially what I want to know is, does the `mean()` function take into account all flights, or only those flights that satisfy the condition when I filter inside the `mean()` function? Because then it wouldn't be the proportion of flights delayed by more than an hour, just the mean of those flights that are delayed by more than an hour.. or not?

Comment: `arr_delay > 60` is not subsetting. It will gives you a logical vector existing of `TRUE`'s or `FALSE`'s. Then all `TRUE`'s are summed up and divided by the total number of flights ending up with percentages of how many flights are later then 60 or so.

Comment: ok thanks that clarifies it, I was confusing it with "mean(arr_delay[arr_delay > 0])" , which is subsetting and calculating the average positive delay only.